# Highcharts - Adding tooltip to ONLY certain dynamically added series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using highcharts, I am adding multiple series to an exist chart.  When adding the series I need to be able to set tooltip on or off depending on the series added.

Here is where I am at:

---

```
widget.chart.addSeries({
      data: newSeries, 
      color: color, 
      tooltip: { 
        enabled: true, 
        formatter: function() { 
          return 'test';
        }  
      }
    });
```

Comment: It does not add the tooltip to that one series as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Inside `chart` options.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var text = false;
        if(this.series.name == "GOOG") {
        // just an example of serie name
        // you can use index or other data too
            text = 'test';
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/guNPL/)